# Plot gps-coordinates in realtime using python (fullscreen view)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot IP-addresses on a word map, I've been using Basemap with animation which does exactly what I want, except that it doesn't display the figure in fullscreen.

To make it in fullscreen I used pygame to set the worldmap (generated from Basemap) as background image and adding circles to every x/y, however, not all cities are being plotted correctly; Gothenburg and Cape Town are correct, New York is nowhere to be found and Sydney is being plotted in Cape Town.

Code for the plotting (Miller Cylindrical Projection):
{

```
map = Basemap(projection='mill', long_0=210)
map.drawcoastlines(color='blue')
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='black')
map.fillcontinents(color='black',lake_color='black')
plt.savefig('map.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=200)

pygame.init()

bmap = pygame.image.load('map.png')
brect = bmap.get_rect()

size = (width, height) = bmap.get_size()

#Gothenburg
lat = 57.70812489
lng = 11.94975493

#Map size 620 x 454

lat = math.radians(lat)
lng = math.radians(lng)

xlat = (width / 2) + (width / (2 * math.pi + 0.4 * lat))

xlng = 1.25 * math.log(math.tan(0.25 * math.pi + 0.4 * lat))
xlng = (height / 2) - (height / (2 * 2.303412543)) * xlng

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.blit(bmap, brect)

pygame.draw.circle(screen, (250, 0, 0), [int(xlat), int(xlng)], 2)
pygame.display.flip()
```

}

I don't really know which of the two approaches which are the best one to go for. Or is there any other solution I might consider?

Comment: You know you can put a matplotlib figure into fullscreen, right? ``plt.draw()`` followed by 
``plt.gcf().canvas.manager.full_screen_toggle()``